# Product get_sale_price is always 0 when using Discount Rules for WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, discount

This is my WordPress configuration (Just upgraded everything, so everything is up to date):
WordPress: 5.4
WooCommerce: 4.0.1
[Discount Rules for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-discount-rules/): 1.9.7

Discount Rules for WooCommerce configuration, per quantity block:
1-4 : 10%
5-24: 20%
25-99999: 30%

This is working perfectly fine on the shop and shop can even get orders properly with discounts.
The thing is that I want to remove SALE! badge from the products as it is automatically added because of 1-4 quantity block which means default 10% site-wide discount as per the configuration.

Now, here is my code in theme's functions.php

```
function wc_custom_replace_sale_text($html, $post, $product) {
  if ($product->is_on_sale()) {
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
    $sale_price = $product->get_sale_price();
    return '<span class="onsale force-display">' . $sale_price . '</span>';
  }
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_sale_flash', 'wc_custom_replace_sale_text', 10, 3 );
```

**Problem**: No matter what I try, I always get `$product->get_sale_price()` result always 0. And, the strange thing is that `$product_is_on_sale()` result is `true`.

Because of this I cannot find out the product discount and so cannot remove SALE label for the 1-4 quantity block.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, this is a bug that you should report on [**Discount Rules for WooCommerce** plugin support pages](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/woo-discount-rules/) as StackOverFlow doesn't handle any software support.

Comment: May be there is a workaround for now as the module is working fine in every aspect, I just cannot get $product->get_sale_price() in hooks. So, may be some other function someone can suggest?

Comment: I have submitted the question on the WordPress plugin page itself: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/product-get_sale_price-is-always-0-when-using-discount-rules-for-woocommerce-plu/

Answer (score 0):

Since rules are applied during runtime, you need to use filters

```php
$discounted_price = apply_filters('advanced_woo_discount_rules_get_product_discount_price_from_custom_price', false, $product, 1, 0, 'all', true);
$wooco_discounted_price = $product->get_sale_price();

if ($discounted_price !== false) {
    if ($discounted_price['discounted_price']  > 0) { 
        // woo discount rule
    } elseif ($wooco_discounted_price > 0) {
        // woocommerce discount
    }
}
```

---

Sources:

- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/advanced_woo_discount_rules_get_product_discount_price_from_custom_price/
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/there-is-no-get_sale_price/#post-13850829

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', function() {
    global $product; // or use wc_get_product() function to get product object
    $sale_price = $product->get_price();
    $discount = apply_filters('advanced_woo_discount_rules_get_product_discount_price', $sale_price, $product);
    if($discount !== false) {
        $sale_price = $discount; // here you can get discounted price
    }
    echo $sale_price;
}, 10 );
```

Here you can get the discounted price.
This event is introduced in Discount Rules version 2.6.0.
So make sure you have Discount Rules version 2.6.0 or above.
Here is the developer documentation link -> https://docs.flycart.org/en/articles/7907342-developer-documentation